# How do you pose a model without the mirror also moving?

Tags: bones, mirror, pose-mode, mirror-modifier

I used the mirror modifier to create the body and added bones but when I try to pose it the mirror still takes affect and half the bones don't affect the model at all. How do you stop it from doing this?
[image: Mirror Modifier]
[image: Posing]

Comment: You have to apply the mirror modifier to create the full body as a mesh. The armature can only affect real meshes, not "virtual" ones generated by a mirror. And then the new vertices of the mirrored side have to be parented to the according bones via weight-painting.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann How do you apply the modifier? What is weight painting?

Comment: in the modifier, click on the little down arrow > Apply, or select the modifier and Ctrl A

Comment: Well, looks like I'm not firm enough in those things. Go to the answer by @joshsanfelici for more information. But if you have no idea what weight painting is you should probably check some tutorials... because there might be situations where the automatic parenting to an armature isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some rules that need to be followed if you want to use a mirror modifier in animation:

The mirror modifier has to be upper (first evaluated) in the stack than the armature modifier; it has to have its "Vertex groups" option checked, and (before parenting) every couple of simmetric bones have to share the same name, except for an accepted suffix, a list of which you can find in the Blender manual (some commons: .L .R, .l .r, .left .right, .....).

[image]